# Chapter 5 Ruby on Rails tutorial - Git merge throwing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I ran the following commands

```
$ bundle exec rake test
$ git add -A
$ git commit -m "Finish layout and routes"
$ git checkout master
$ git merge filling-in-layout
```

after running the last "merge" command it throws out the following error :

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
        spring/50c4ccb1d8f630979e84c03ba14676d1.pid
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting

My .gitignore file is as follows :

   # Ignore bundler config.
/.bundle

# Ignore the default SQLite database.
/db/*.sqlite3
/db/*.sqlite3-journal

# Ignore all logfiles and tempfiles.
/log/*
!/log/.keep
/tmp
# Ignore Spring files.
/spring/*.pid
```

I dnt see the merged files , also I am unable to switch back to branch - filling-in-layout. The app has stopped working on the cloud Ide server.

Please throw some light on the same .

Answer (score 4):

Try run :

```
git checkout spring/50c4ccb1d8f630979e84c03ba14676d1.pid
```

And then try merge branches again.

```
git merge filling-in-layout
```

Your local changes to file `spring/50c4ccb1d8f630979e84c03ba14676d1.pid` giving this error.

There might be some issue with your `.gitignore` file. Because you already have `/spring/*.pid` in your gitignore file but it still checking this file. Might be your previous commit have this file.

Comment: The issue still prevails - what happens is whenever I change branch , it throws out the .pid error .. dnt know what i am doin wrong

Comment: Try remove all pid files from your git library using `git rm require 'date'` and then push this to your origin. You will not get this error

Comment: I removed a trailing space from the line "/spring/*.pid " for git to actually ignore the spring line. Don't know why that happened though, git is [https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore](supposed to ignore) trailing spaces.

Answer (score 2):

The spring process probably got too big. I had the same problem.

you can use `pkill -15 -f spring`

and here is more info from https://www.railstutorial.org/book/static_pages

> On Unix-like systems such as Linux and OS X, user and system tasks
>   each take place within a well-defined container called a process. To
>   see all the processes on your system, you can use the ps command with
>   the aux options:
>
> $ ps aux To filter the processes by type, you can run the results of
>   ps through the grep pattern-matcher using a Unix pipe |:
>
> $ ps aux | grep spring   ubuntu 12241 0.3 0.5 589960 178416 ? Ssl
>   Sep20 1:46   spring app | sample_app | started 7 hours ago The result
>   shown gives some details about the process, but the most important
>   thing is the first number, which is the process id, or pid. To
>   eliminate an unwanted process, use the kill command to issue the Unix
>   kill code (which happens to be 9) to the pid:
>
> $ kill -15 12241 This is the technique I recommend for killing
>   individual processes, such as a rogue Rails server (with the pid found
>   via ps aux | grep server), but sometimes it’s convenient to kill all
>   the processes matching a particular process name, such as when you
>   want to kill all the spring processes gunking up your system. In this
>   particular case, you should first try stopping the processes with the
>   spring command itself:
>
> $ spring stop Sometimes this doesn’t work, though, and you can kill
>   all the processes with name spring using the pkill command as follows:
>
> $ pkill -15 -f spring Any time something isn’t behaving as expected
>   or a process appears to be frozen, it’s a good idea to run ps aux to
>   see what’s going on, and then run kill -15  or pkill -15 -f
>    to clear things up.

Answer (score 0):

I am very late for the solution i guess but i was having the same issue. It turned out that i was running the guard test which was giving the spring file error. Just exit from the guard menu and then use `git commit -am "anything you want"`